# Handling Convergence for Derivative of a Distribution

Tags: convergence-divergence, distribution-theory

Obtain the derivative of the distribution defined by

$\rho [t] = \int_0^\infty \frac{t(x)}{\sqrt{x}}dx$, and express your answer in the form of an integral over $x$ of a formula that involves $t(x)$ but not $t'(x)$.

Progress: So we know for distribution $\rho'[t] = -\rho[t']$. Applying this we have $-\int_0^\infty \frac{t'(x)}{\sqrt{x}}dx$. We (naively) apply integration by parts to obtain $\left.\frac{t(x)}{\sqrt{x}}\right|_0^\infty - \frac{1}{2}\int_0^\infty \frac{t(x)}{x^{3/2}} dx$. However now this integral doesn't converge, since t(x) can be any smooth function, replace it by it's maximum and you see the integral no longer converges. How do we rectify this?

Comment: why is this question a bad question? should i not repost it?

Answer (score 1):

Let's apply integration by parts less naively, then.

$$
\begin{split}
-\int_0^\infty \frac{t'(x)}{\sqrt{x}}dx 
&= \lim_{a\to 0^+}-\int_a^\infty \frac{t'(x)}{\sqrt{x}}dx \\
&= \lim_{a\to 0^+} -\left.\frac{t(x)}{\sqrt{x}}\right|_a^\infty - \frac{1}{2}\int_a^\infty \frac{t(x)}{x^{3/2}} dx  \\
&= \lim_{a\to 0^+} \frac{t(a)}{\sqrt{a}}- \frac{1}{2}\int_a^\infty \frac{t(x)}{x^{3/2}} dx
\end{split}
$$
Since $t$ is smooth, $t(a)-t(0)$ is $O(a)$, which allows us to continue with 
$$
\begin{split}
\dots & =\lim_{a\to 0^+} \frac{t(0)}{\sqrt{a}}- \frac{1}{2}\int_a^\infty \frac{t(x)}{x^{3/2}} dx \\
& =\lim_{a\to 0^+} \frac{1}{2}\int_a^\infty \frac{t(0)-t(x)}{x^{3/2}} dx  \\
& =\frac{1}{2}\int_0^\infty \frac{t(0)-t(x)}{x^{3/2}} dx 
\end{split}
$$
The last integral converges. (why?)

Comment: So, you replace $t(a)$ with $t(0)$, since it's difference is small, so you can take the derivative and stick it into the integral? then the numerator should go to zero faster than the denominator? why that is, I'm not sure. Why does it converge?

Comment: $t(0) - t(x) = xt'(\xi_x)$ for some $\xi_x\in [0,x]$ by Taylors theorem. So suddenly, $0$ is no problem anymore, and the $+\infty$ border can also be avoided...